# How do I put the values from an external file into an array?

Tags: c++

I am trying to read an external file and put all the strings that are in the file into an array of type string.

This is my main function:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "ReadWords.h"
#include "Writer.h"
#include <cctype>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int count;
    const int size = 10;
    string word_search[size];
    string word;

    cout << "Please enter a filename: " << flush;
    char filename[30];
    cin >> filename;

    ReadWords reader(filename);
    while (reader.isNextWord()){
        count = count + 1;
        reader.getNextWord();

    }

    cout << "Please enter the name of the file with the search words: " << flush;

    char filename1[30];
    cin >> filename1;

    ReadWords reader1(filename1);
    while (reader1.isNextWord()) {
```

This is where I am trying to store the strings in an array called word_search, this is not however currently working. How do I store the strings in the array?

```
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            word_search[i] = word;

        }
    }
```

This is where I am printing the contents of the array to see if I have been successful.

```
    cout << word_search << endl;



    return 0;
}
```

This is where all the methods have been declared in a separate file called ReadWords.cpp:

```
#include "ReadWords.h"
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void ReadWords::close(){
    wordfile.close();

}

ReadWords::ReadWords(const char *filename) {
    //storing user input to use as the filename

        //string filename;

        wordfile.open(filename);

        if (!wordfile) {
            cout << "could not open " << filename << endl;
            exit(1);
        }
}

string ReadWords::getNextWord() {

    string n;


    if(isNextWord()){
        wordfile >> n;
        //cout << n << endl;

        int len = n.length();
        for(int i = 0; i < len ; i++) {

            if (ispunct(n[i]))
                    {
                        n.erase(i--, 1);
                        len = n.length();
                    }
        }
            cout << n << endl;
        return n;

    }
}

bool ReadWords::isNextWord() {

        if (wordfile.eof()) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? The for loop can very well work if it is set up correctly.

Comment: My first guesswork tells me you want to replace `word_search[i] = word;
` with `word_search.push_back(word);`

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: Ah yes, that famous function `((std::string)[10])::push_back`.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You read the question more thoroughly than I did. I commend you for that. I'm also somewhat impressed.

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe: It wasn't terribly troublesome to spot that there are no vectors in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant

```
    size_t count = 0;
    while (reader.isNextWord()){
        word_search[count] = reader.getNextWord();
        ++count;
    }
```

Also, consider using std::vector instead of an array. Also, variable "word" is unused.
To print contents use

```
   for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        cout << word_search[i] << endl;
```